# Apache doesn't serve files in "javascript" directory. Why?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, debian

All of the sudden I started getting 404s for files like `http://example.localhost/javascript/jquery.min.js`

Earlier everything was working just fine. I didn't change any configs, at least not manually.

But now if I'd try to access the `/javascript` directory itself I would get `"Cannot serve directory /usr/share/javascript/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive` in the Apache error log.

Comment: I just had the same issue in froxlor, so for search engine purpose I am adding that comment here.

Comment: Just had the same issue on ubuntu server... Spent 4 hours trying to migrate our web app from windows to a linux server. Linux is like the french, overly complicated.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I was trying to find solution to this on Stack Overflow, but I couldn't. So I'm just leaving this here if anyone happens to encounter the same problem.

So why the hell would it look in the /usr/share/javascript instead of what I had configured in the VirtualHost. To figure that out I did something like the following:

```
$ cd /etc/apache2
$ grep -R Alias * | grep share

...
conf-enabled/javascript-common.conf:Alias /javascript /usr/share/javascript/
...
```

After googling for that configuration file name I found [some explanation](http://www.matthewjwhite.co.uk/blog/2010/05/27/opsview-users-beware-javascript-common-package/).

I don't know why, but I had the [javascript-common](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/javascript-common) package installed.
It doesn't seem harmful to get rid of it, so doing `$ sudo apt-get purge javascript-common` solved the problem for me.

Comment: I was having this issue for more than a week and this solved it! I know this is an old answer, but thank you!

Comment: `sudo a2disconf javascript-common.conf` is a gentler solution, though I would have preferred explosives. Serious google-fu is required to get here. Thanks for figuring this out.

Answer (score 14):

You don't need to edit the conf file or purge the package just disable it.

```
a2disconf javascript-common
service apache2 reload
```

If for some reason you want to use that conf:

```
a2enconf javascript-common
service apache2 reload
```

Comment: Clean surgical solution.  The others are sledgehammers.

Answer (score 11):

#### The [issue](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/javascript-common):

> Web applications that use JavaScript need to distribute it through
> HTTP. Using a common path for every script avoids the need to enable
> this path in the HTTP server for every package.

This is the package that creates `/usr/share/javascript` alias and enables it in the Apache webserver.

#### Recommended fix

And that's it. You won't have any other problem with javascript directories. Another fix could be to rename `/usr/share/javascript/` to `/usr/share/javascript-common/`, then adjust the Alias in `javascript-common.conf` to point to the renamed directory. I am still not sure if this will affect any future update.

#### Another Fix:

Go to `/etc/apache2/conf-available/javascript-common.conf`. You will find this:

```
Alias /javascript /usr/share/javascript/
<Directory "/usr/share/javascript/">
     Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
</Directory>
```

So you just have to comment these lines (with the `#` char) (it is not recommended to edit the file directly in conf-enabled) to avoid the forbidden error. After that, do this:

```
a2disconf javascript-common
a2enconf javascript-common
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm on a [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) machine, and there is no a2disconf command. I found the `/etc/apache2/conf.d` directory is a link to `/etc/javascript-common/javascript-common.conf`.

I went and edited that file (as root) and changed it to alias `/javascript-common` instead of `/javascript` by changing the top line to

```
Alias /javascript-common /usr/share/javascript/
```

and saving it and restarting Apache.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem on an Ubuntu system. Apparently the `javascript-common` package was hosed at some point in time and the configure script wouldn't run properly. Removing `javascript-common` and reinstalling with apt-get would not fix it. I had to:

```
dpkg --purge javascript-common

apt-get install javascript-common
```

And that seemed to fix the problem. This is an [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) LTS (Xenial Xerus) system that was upgraded from [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) LTS (Trusty Tahr).

Comment: OMG - why is there even this package? It pollutes the complete /javascript namespace. In my case I had also Ubuntu 16.04.6

Answer (score -4):

Uninstall `apache2` and delete these folders:

- rm -R /var/www/html/
- rm -R /etc/apache2

Then reinstall `javascript-common` and `apache2`.