# '/javascript' named directory does not get access to my localhost. Why?

Tags: javascript, directory, localhost

I am having a Ubuntu 16.04 and it is running Apache 2.4.18. So when I created a directory named "javascript" in my directory /var/www/html.
Then I also created a html file. And when I tried to run it on my localhost as show below:

localhost/javascript/

It is showing error as show below:

"You don't have permission to access /javascript/ on this server."

And when I created same html file in but in another directory named "learn_js" it is not showing any error. Why ???

Comment: I'm running into this too. If I rename the directory, it works, so it has nothing to do with permissions or contents. Somebody decided to make Apache ignore a directory named `javascript`. Wish they'd asked me first... grumble, grumble.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the host config file of your Apache server. Add the following:

```
Order allow,deny 
Allow from all
```

If that doesn't work, simply *change the permissions* for the `/javascript/` folder.

```
chmod 755 /javascript/
```

Comment: I have changed the permission of the folder but it not showing the required result whereas all other folders have the same permission and they are running without any errors.

Comment: How about deleting the folder and creating a new one with the same name?

Comment: Already tried creating a new one with same name.

Answer (score 0):

Solution might be:

```
sudo a2disconf javascript-common.conf
```

This package redirects `Alias /javascript /usr/share/javascript/`. Isn't that an ill-manered thing to do by default?

Thanks to [@uKolka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21706068/673991) for finding this.