# Why are my javascript files the only files that get a 404?

Tags: javascript, php, html, lamp

I'm having a really strange problem where everything loads, but my javascript folder and files are getting the 404 error. Every other folder path to my css and php files are working fine.

I checked the usual problems: wrong folder path, misnamed folder both in my header and the folder path on my server.

/var/www/website.com/html/javascript/files.js

How the paths are declared:

```
<script src= "/javascript/StickyBar.js"></script>

<script src="/javascript/pvc.js"></script>
```

I have it working in xampp on localhost just fine. localhost works exactly as intended, no 404s and the code runs perfect. I transferred the entire folder system into my server and /javacript/files.js are getting 404s on the actual website.

GET [website]/javascript/StickyBar.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

GET [website]/javascript/pvc.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

If you're wondering why I have them absolute instead of relative, it's because I have them declared (first code snippet) in header.php in a folder that's accessed by index.php on multiple folder levels using

```
<?php include '/view/header.php' ?>
```

(view is in folder path and works) so a relative path wouldn't work as the relativity shifts depending on the page.

The strange thing is that according to chrome, it downloads. I'm not sure if I'm reading it wrong, because it doesn't show up in sources on chrome's debugger. The download is the blue part of the bar and it seems to match with their file sizes in regards to download time. There's also a much longer green part of the bar that marks the wait time.

I'm running ubuntu server 18.04 with lamp on it running as it should. Everything is updated.

If you need more details, let me know.

1. File path gist [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMrEH.png)
2. Those two lines are in header.php. header.php is included in index.php and every other page folder i.e. in home.php, about.php, pages like that.
3. header.php is the header file with typical html layout from DOCTYPE to head and header [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z8sM.png)
4. apache server vhost:

   ServerAdmin admin@example.com

   ServerName example.com

   ServerAlias www.example.com

   DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/html

Comment: I am not sure about this, but I had a similar problem and it was because Linux uses *case-sensitive* filenames and Windows and Mac are *case-insensitive*. I think It's better to use *lower-case* names if you are doing cross-platform development. So, In your case, you will need to rename the files to lowercase and also link them in all lower-case.

Comment: If that's the case, then pvc.js should work no problem then, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. Apache redirected my folder named javascript to usr/share/javascript. Though the explanation said it specified the folder under usr/share/javascript-common , I did not get that. All I ended up doing is changing my javascript folder name to js. This was the post I found it in.

[Apache doesn't serve files in "javascript" directory. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706067/apache-doesnt-serve-files-in-javascript-directory-why)

Sure enough, in etc/apache2/conf-enabled/javascript-common , an Alias /javascript superseded my call for /javascript in /html. I wonder if that's a better practice to storing javascript files. I'll look more into this.

Thanks for your time!

Should I delete this since it's technically a duplicate?

Comment: I don't think you can now that there are answers posted. But now that I've voted to close it as a duplicate I think you can just close it yourself IIRC.

Comment: Yep, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

1. could you show your directory structure?
2. which file did you put these two lines in:

```
    <script src= "/javascript/StickyBar.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascript/pvc.js"></script>
```

3. `it's because I have them declared (first code snippet) in header.php` what did you declared in header.php, could you post here?
4. Are you using nginx or apache server on your Ubuntu Server? could you show the nginx or apache config file(the vhost part)?

Comment: edited the question with info... I'm still learning how to properly make edits and answer questions