# Javascript Failed to load (404) but path is correct. How come?

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404

I have this problem on my development server. This piece of code :

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/front.js?v=33"></script>
```

Returns the following error in the console :

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

I checked the path, and it is correct. Besides, it works correctly on my local machine, I guess it wouldn't be the case if the problem was about the path being misstyped.

I also checked the permissions on my server - the apache user (`www-data`) has access to all the arborescence of the website in reading.

```sh
drwxrwxr-x+  2 www-data www-data 4.0K Aug  2 11:34 javascript
```

The other resources (like the style sheets and the images) are loading just fine, so I'm quite baffled. What else could cause this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out something. I didn't know this so I couldn't quite find it here. It is the folder name that Apache doesn't like ([Apache doesn't serve files in "javascript" directory. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706067/apache-doesnt-serve-files-in-javascript-directory-why))