# Are there disallowed directory names in html (e.g. javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a website (and testing it on a local apache server).  I had my javascript files in a directory called "javascript".  When I tried to access these files, I received a 404 file not found error.

After searching for a solution, and checking for spelling mistakes **repeatedly**, I changed the directory name to "js", since that seemed to be more of a standard, and I couldn't possibly misspell two letters.  That suddenly made my file discoverable, as did a number of other directory names.

I have also tried sourcing a css file from a directory called "javascript" and determined that that does not work either.

Does anyone know *why* a directory called "javascript" is undiscoverable to html? Are there any other reserved directory names?

Comment: HTML doesn't care directory names, your server (or framework) might have some reserved or forbidden names.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache doesn't serve files in "javascript" directory. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706067/apache-doesnt-serve-files-in-javascript-directory-why)

Comment: There are no reserved directory names in HTML or JavaScript because neither HTML nor JavaScript has a concept of directories.

Comment: @theblackgigant yes, thanks