# Laravel app returning Forbidden (403) on /javascript URL pattern mapped to a Controller

Tags: laravel

For some reason, I need to map /* to a Controller in Laravel. I am using below mapping:

```
Route::get('/{slug}', [MyController::class, 'index']);
```

It works fine for all URLs tested, but when I access example.com/javascript
Instead of calling Controller, it returns 403 - Forbidden. I do not have 'javascript' folder inside the 'public' folder.

How to configure Laravel, it shall go to routes and delegate request to related Controller?

Comment: 403 means it's hitting *something* or it'd be getting a 404. Is the 403 a Laravel 403, or is the error from your webserver? What does `php artisan route:list` output?

Comment: Not sure, may be its being returned by the Apache. When I list, GET|HEAD  {slug} .... is displayed there, at end.

Comment: From an alias URL example.com/branch2/javascript, it works. It seems, Apache is doing something on root domain and the request is not getting passed to Laravel, but point is, how to confirm and disable this?

Comment: I'd look at your Apache config. Perhaps you've got some configuration to treat `images`, `css`, `javascript`, etc. as static folders with far-future expires and it's conflicting?

Comment: got the solution, it was related to javascript-common conf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31986981/317716 .. thanks for point to right direction

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you have registered this route in your `web.php` route file, since you do not specify `/api/` in the example url.

If you have other routes registered such as `Route::get('/some-route', [ExampleController::class, 'index']);` it will work fine when you visit `example.com/some-route`, but everything else will fall into the `Route::get('/{slug}', [MyController::class, 'index']);` route, meaning the framework will assume that whatever you write after `example.com/` is the `{slug}`, and then it likely fails an auth check in your MyController class for this reason.

I hope this clarify things for you.

Comment: Its falls into defined pattern for example.com/some-route. Only issue is when 'javascript' term specifically. It fails to capture example.com/javascript

Answer (score -1):

If you add parameter it'll works fine otherwise by deafult laravel route mechanism can't understand. please try to put "/p" Short parameter before your slug url.

Make sure to clear your route cache after making changes to your routes

Comment: Haven't defined '?!javascript$' any where. routes cache clearing also do not work.

Comment: You can put any parameter before slug, and check. 
Example : ```Route::get('/p/{slug}', [MyController::class, 'index']);```

Comment: Then it works, but for some reason (e.g. small and clean URL from SEO perspective), I do not want to put /p/ in URLs